# How can a Sub handle FormClosing and Button.Click?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form in a Windows Forms VB.NET application.  I want to catch a form closing but also a Button.Click.  The problem is that the EventArgs seem incompatible. Is it possible to have one Sub catch both events? Or do I need to have one Sub for each?

```
Private Sub Frm_MapParts_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing, Btn_Update.Click
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you still wish to leave this form?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation, "MATCHING INCOMPLETE!") = vbNo Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Sub
```

In this example, Btn_Update.Click creates an error when paired with FormClosingEventArgs. But also using EventArgs means that e.Cancel doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe, create a function for the `MsgBox` to ask and returns a `Boolean`. Call it from `FormClosing` and `Button.Click` events. `True` close, `False` cancel. And use the `MessageBox` instead of `MsgBox`.

Comment: *"using EventArgs means that e.Cancel doesn't exist"*. Exactly, so what's the point here? You can't cancel a `Click` event so why are you trying to use a single event handler in the first place? The whole point of using a single event handler for multiple events is so that you can do the same thing in each case but you obviously want to do something different in each case so you should be using separate event handlers. If part of what you want to do is the same then, as always, put that in a method of its own and call that method in both places that functionality is needed.

Comment: I haven't actually tried this but it's what I'd try to do first.  Set the event handler to receive regular eventargs, not the specialized type, then check the sender type, and based on the sender type, recast the eventargs.  That failing, I'd create a sub "closehandler", and just have both of your 2 event handlers call it.  I'm pretty sure that I've seen something of this sort explained right here on SO in the past.